# Why is an intermediate result cast to long before it is assigned to an int?

Tags: c++, casting, multiplication, integer-overflow

In many of the coding streams and solutions in Codeforces and Codechef I have seen that when the number is bit large and we need to assign it to int then instead of casting it to int we cast it to long

```
int maxAreaOfCake(int h, int w, vector<int>& hCuts, vector<int>& vCuts)
{
    hCuts.push_back(0);
    hCuts.push_back(h);

    vCuts.push_back(0);
    vCuts.push_back(w);

    int MOD = 100000007;

    sort(hCuts.begin(), hCuts.end());
    sort(vCuts.begin(), vCuts.end());

    int horizontal = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)hCuts.size() - 1; i++) horizontal = max(horizontal, hCuts[i+1] - hCuts[i]);
    

    int vertical = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)vCuts.size() - 1; i++) vertical = max(vertical, vCuts[i+1] - vCuts[i]);
    
    return (int) ((long)horizontal%MOD * (long)vertical%MOD)%MOD;
}
```

It is the solution of MaxAreaOfCake question in leetcode. Here as the return type is int finally we are converting to int but before doing that we are first converting it to long. when i try to change the long to int i am getting the runtime error. If any one knows the answer please do share :)

Comment: What does "bit large" mean?

Comment: What is the type of `y`? This cast probably doesn't do anything.

Comment: Competitive programming is its own thing and should *definitely* not be used as an guide on how to program well. Practices used by "competitive programming" are very bad in real practical code.

Comment: "*coding streams and solutions in Codeforces and Codechef*" Please do not take these sources seriously as examples of good practice. Basically nothing there should be used in actual programs.

Comment: The cast looks useless. It should be equivalent to `int x = y;`.

Comment: Provide a real code snippet (because you have seen it, right?). Then we can comment on it. From what you show and tell so far all we can say is "nonsensical". The assignment as it stands will on many implementations generate a "narrowing" warning: Not all long values can be represented in an int, and the coder should make sure that there is no overflow. As such, the cast to long makes only sense if all possible values of y can be represented in a long, and *then* you must check the int value limits to make sure it fits in an int, and *then* explicitly cast to *int*!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Please do check now I have updated the question with the actual code snippet

Comment: Voted to reopen since it now makes sense.

Comment: Presumably `MOD` can be larger than 46340, in that case `MOD*MOD` can overflow an `int`. So the computation is done as `long`. But the final result is modulo `MOD`, which again might fit in an `int`.

Comment: The use of `long` in this code only makes sense if `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`, which is not guaranteed by every compiler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau One should static assert that MOD is smaller than the square root (by bit shift using numeric limits, I guess) of MAX_LONG. Then it would not matter if int and long were the same; it would potentially be redundant but always suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in question is

`return (int) ((long)horizontal%MOD * (long)vertical%MOD)%MOD;`

The casts to long make sure that the expression `(long)horizontal%MOD * (long)vertical%MOD` is a multiplication of two `long` values. C and C++ compute the result of arithmetic operations as the "largest" type of their operands; if you multiply two `int`s, the result is `int`as well. If the mathematical result is too large for an int, that results in a signed overflow which is undefined behavior. That would happen here if `horizontal%MOD * vertical%MOD` were larger than the largest `int`, for example because the operands are larger than the square root of the maximum `int` value. In order to prevent that the code casts the operands to `long`, in the hopes that `long`'s value range is larger (which may or may not be true). If it is true the result will typically always fit into a `long` (because typically the maximum `int` is smaller than the square root of the largest `long`). The result of the multiplication is then used to compute its modulo `MOD`, which is never larger than `MOD-1` and hence smaller than the maximum `int`. It is therefore safe to cast the end result back to `int`, which is what the first `(int)`
does. But the large intermediate result, before the final modulo, must be computed in a larger value range type.

Looking at circumstances one would have to perform in order to make this logic robust (if  `long` and `int` have the same value range, the casts are futile) I wish there were a template in `std::numeric_limits<T>` like `bool would_overflow(T2 arg)` that for every arg of type T2 returns whether that value is convertible to T without overflowing.